# Filter out serieses with currently unset values from Prometheus query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Given the query below:

```
avg(helm_chart_info{chart=~"foo",namespace="dev-fe",release=~"bar.+"}) by (release)
```

Is it possible to filter out series which are currently (at this instant) unset (i.e. no value)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "unset" in Prometheus, only time series without recent data (as governed by staleness). So that query will already do that.